# Display checkboxes in two columns with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using **Bootstrap** to display the checkboxes in two columns. Short example:

```
<fieldset class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <span>Here is the text</span>
   </label>
</fieldset>
```

Here is an image of
[the checkboxes in two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O721.png) In the image you can see the "transportation" checkbox dropping much lower than the other checkboxes.

How can I prevent the empty space between the checkboxes, in certain screen sizes?
I can't change the way I'm displaying the label and the span inside it, but I can add classes to them.

Comment: What space are you talking about? Can you provide a working JsFiddle / ...?

Comment: OT: you should either add a `legend` element as first child of your existing `fieldset` or remove that `fieldset`. Resource: https://accessibility.blog.gov.uk/2016/07/22/using-the-fieldset-and-legend-elements/

Comment: Didn't know that @FelipeAls, thank you for the link!

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem in this Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/2cOHBrCA7o Please provide a "working" one that reproduces your problem (if you're using BS 4, you'll have to start over a new Ply to choose BS4 at the very beginning or be logged to change version (I think))

Comment: The "empty space" is happening because the content of your `col-*` varies in height.

Comment: That solves the problem @ZimSystem, thanks! I added a fixed height. If you want to add it as an answer, I can later accept it.

Answer (score 5):

**You just have to add this CSS:**

```
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  list-style: none;
}
```

**Made some changes in your HTML**

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul>

       <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span>Here is the text</span>
          </label>
       </li>

       <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span>Here is the text</span>
          </label>
       </li>

       <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span>Here is the text</span>
          </label>
       </li>

       <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span>Here is the text</span>
          </label>
       </li>

       <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span>Here is the text</span>
          </label>
       </li>



       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your divs allign in a row like this:

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class="row">
    <fieldset class="col-sm-6">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Here is the text</span>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="col-sm-6">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Here is the text</span>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a row, and container divs, but still the problem persists.